# jQuery - check if variable is dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there any way to check if given variable is **not-empty** jQuery object or native DOM element?

so it would be like

```
isDomElem( $("#some-existing-element") ); //returns true
isDomElem( $("#some-existing-element")[0] ); //returns true
isDomElem( $("#non-existing-element")[0] ); //returns false
isDomElem( "#some-existing-element" ); //returns false
isDomElem( [0,1,2] ); //returns false
//etc...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check if the object passed in is an `instanceof jQuery` or an `instanceof HTMLElement`. If it is `return true;`. Otherwise, `return false`.

```
function isDomElem(obj) {
      if(obj instanceof HTMLCollection && obj.length) {
          for(var a = 0, len = obj.length; a < len; a++) {
              if(!checkInstance(obj[a])) {
                  console.log(a);
                  return false;   
              }
          }     
          return true;                
      } else {
          return checkInstance(obj);  
      }

      function checkInstance(elem) {
          if((elem instanceof jQuery && elem.length) || elem instanceof HTMLElement) {
              return true;  
          }
          return false;        
      }
}
```

Optionally, instead of returning `true` or `false`, you could do some other action. You could also split each option out and do a separate action depending on which one the object is an instance of `jQuery` or `HTMLElement`. You have lots of choices to choose from.

```js
$(function () {
  var temp1 = $('div'),
      temp2 = $('div')[0],
      temp3 = "foo",
      temp4 = ['bar'],
      temp5 = $('span'),
      temp6 = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  
  alert(isDomElem(temp1));
  alert(isDomElem(temp2));
  alert(isDomElem(temp3));
  alert(isDomElem(temp4));
  alert(isDomElem(temp5));
  alert(isDomElem(temp6));
  
  function isDomElem(obj) {
    
      if(obj instanceof HTMLCollection && obj.length) {
        
        for(var a = 0, len = obj.length; a < len; a++) {
            if(!checkInstance(obj[a])) {
                return false;   
            }
        }
               
        return true;
               
      } else {
          return checkInstance(obj);  
      }
        
      function checkInstance(elem) {
          if((elem instanceof jQuery && elem.length) || elem instanceof HTMLElement) {
              return true;  
          }
          return false;        
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<p class="test"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
```

**EDIT:**

*@RickHitchcock* made a very valid point regarding the function returning an instance of jQuery with no matched elements. For this reason, I've updated the function to take into account not only if the object is an instanceof jQuery but also if the object has a length, indicating whether a DOM element was found.

**EDIT:**

An additional edit was made per *@AdamPietrasiak*'s comment below regarding instances of `HTMLCollections` returning false. In this case, if the `obj` passed in is an instance of `HTMLCollection`, each element is passed to the internal `checkInstance` function. Any element which is not a DOM node triggers the function to throw an overall `false` regardless of whether there was an element in the list (i.e. for instances of `HTMLCollection` the function treats it as an all or nothing).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `instanceof` does not work the way you want if the object is from another document (e.g. from an iframe or a different window).

Comment: This incorrectly returns true for `isDomElem( $("#non-existing-element") )`

Comment: @RickHitchcock The function name may be misleading but it returns what the OP asked for. The OP wanted the function to return true if the given variable was a jQuery object or a DOM Element. He/She never specified if the jQuery object represented an empty DOM Element.

Comment: I assumed OP would want to return false if an element didn't exist.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Probably a safe assumption to make. I chose to fulfill the request as presented

Comment: I've updated question with empty jQuery result case.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thanks for the comment and suggestion. After thinking about it some more, it doesn't really make sense to return a jQuery object with an empty matched set as true. I've updated the function and credited you with the advice for the additional error checking.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine, great job!

Comment: Well, returns `false` for `document.getElementsByClassName("a")` if there would be 2 elements with `a` class. I'm not sure what to think about it.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak Per your comment, I've made an edit and credited you with a comment in the answer. For instances of `HTMLCollection` each element is checked to ensure it matches the criteria. If any one element fails, the overall test fails.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this covers all cases:

```js
console.clear();
function isDomElem(el) {
  return el instanceof HTMLElement || 
         el[0] instanceof HTMLElement ?
         true : false;
}

console.log(isDomElem($("#some-existing-element"))); //returns true
console.log(isDomElem($("#some-existing-element")[0])); //returns true
console.log(isDomElem($("#non-existing-element"))); //returns false
console.log(isDomElem("#some-existing-element")); //returns false
console.log(isDomElem([0,1,2])); //returns false
console.log(isDomElem(document.getElementsByClassName("a"))); //returns true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-existing-element" class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: I'd add instanceof condition to it as there is possibility of non-dom object that have propeties that would make it return true for it

Comment: It would be unusual for a non-dom object to have a `nodeType`, but you make a good point.

Comment: Unusual but possible for false-positive.

Comment: I've updated with a much simplified version.  I can't think of a way to create false positives at the moment.

Comment: `console.log(isDomElem($("<div></div>"))); //returns true` which is not as expected because the the `<div></div>` hasn't been attached to the DOM yet and therefore shouldn't be considered an existing element.